# Loading a .phtml file within an Observer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I'm trying to load my .phtml files in the template folder within my observer but I'm getting this error

> Invalid template file: 'VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml' in module: 'VENDOR_MYModule' block's name: 'category_0'

Here's the structure of my files

```
app
 + code
    + VENDOR
      + MYModule
        + Block
            - Category.php
        + Controller
            + Category
               - Index.php
        + etc
            + frontend
                - routes.xml
        + Observer
            - CategoryObserver.php
        + view
            + frontend
                + layout
                    - header_category_index.xml
                + templates
                    + category
                        - index.phtml
```

Now the content of my `Block/Category.php` is below

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MYModule\Block;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

The content of my `Controller/Category/Index.php` is below

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MYModule\Controller\Category;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;     
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }   
}
```

The content of the `layout/header_category_index.xml` is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category" name="category_items" template="VENDOR_MYModule::category/index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

The content of my `.phtml` is just a simple `<h1>Hello world</h1>`. Now in my `Observer` I'm trying to load this `.phtml` file but I can't load it and getting the error. The content of my Observer `Observer\CategoryObserver` is below

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{           
    $layout = $this->_layout->create();
    $block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml')->toHtml();        

    $this->_logger->debug("[DEBUG]::" , [$block]);
}
```

Here's the content of my `events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="category-edit" instance="VENDOR\MYModule\Observer\CategoryObserver" />
    </event>   
</config>
```

But I'm getting the error as mentioned above. Any idea on how to load this .phtml file to the observer? I'm planning to write the content of this .phtml file to a .txt file. But I can't proceed since I tried outputting it but I'm still getting an error

> UPDATE:

Tried my code using the Frontend controller/action access and the block successfully loaded. Now I think there's another way or implementation when retrieving the .phtml in the Admin part or in the Observer. Also note that the observer is triggered when I try to edit/save a catalog->category.

Comment: On the event `catalog_category_save_after`  add a block is a totally wrong idea.

For creating a block you need a layout object.

Comment: @AmitBera what do you mean I need to create a layout object? Can you please provide a code sample. I'm triggering the retrieval of .phtml file when I try to save the category. Would appreciate if you can provide on how to implement it. I'm quite new with magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
    $block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml')->toHtml();
```

to

```
    $block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::category/index.phtml')->toHtml();
```

**[Update]**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CatalogCategorySaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $layout;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $this->layout->createBlock('SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Category')->setTemplate('SR_MagentoCommunity::category/index.phtml')->toHtml();
        error_log($block);
    }
}
```

Template location:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/base/templates/category/index.phtml

And

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="category-edit" instance="SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer\CatalogCategorySaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: I tried this. I made the `Category` as capital because that's the name of the folder inside the template folder. I tried changing the name to small letter both from the file and the folder itself but I get the same error

Comment: Can you added observer full class and which event do you observe?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Tried this but the same thing. Do I need to run anything to make this work? I tried running `bin/magento cache:clean`, `bin/magento setup:di:compile` but nothing works

Comment: You don't need anything. app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/events.xml this is the location of events.xml

Comment: Do you check file location?

Comment: @SohelRana, is there any way to pass the array variable from observer to template file?

Comment: Ho sohel can you pls help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330251/57334

Answer (score 0):

```
$block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::category/index.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: How is this different from my sample? Aside from the difference of Upper Case `C` and lowercase `C`?

Comment: Hi aravind can you help me : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330251/57334